# Ubuntu 10.04 + Lighttpd. can't bind to port: :: 80 Address already in use

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, lighttpd

I've had a machine running Ubuntu 9.10, with lighttpd and PHP.
After the OS update to Ubuntu 10.04, it installed apache2 automatically for some reason (I believe it is due to some dependencies php -> apache). Anyway I removed apache2 permanently, but starting lighttpd fails, giving provided error -

> can't bind to port: :: 80 Address already in use

using

> sudo lsof -i :80

results in **empty** list!!

What is wrong?!

thanks in advance,
m.

Comment: Could you post result of `netstat -lpn`?

Comment: here it goes ... http://pastebin.com/EH3BwQcP

Comment: Please show the output of netstat -tulpen

Comment: Are you sure the result is everything from `netstat -lpn` ? Because it shows only sockets. Did you run it as root? The result should look like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=M8ZuqTrX

Comment: indeed, my mistake. I thought it was just result of some commands I tried before. there you go : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xKjfLqAt

however I don't see anything on 80 :(

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Q9EKz9NG
however nothing on 80 :(

Comment: This result is useful, but it doesn't show any daemon listening on port 80. Have you tried to open http://127.0.0.1:80 ?

Comment: In this case the error message is misleading. Do a "grep -i lighttpd /var/log/messages" and see if you can find something helpful.

Comment: nothing related to lighttpd there :(

Comment: I did. 
telnet fails to connect to localhost on 80

Comment: please try "sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd status"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running lighttpd as root (sudo)? Normal users can't launch processes that bind on ports < 1024 ...

Comment: I am running as root :)
'sudo service lighttpd start' ;)

Comment: @migajek the "::" make me think of IPv6... have you tried disabling
IPv6 support in lighttpd.conf ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with replacing the config file with the default one, than copying custom settings back to the new config. I haven't compared the files, however the only change after all the modifications is the order of extension (modules) loading, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by commenting out below line and the IPv6 Virtual Host in /etc/lighttpd.conf file.

```
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this was overlooked or not showing up for some reason, but skype uses port 80, so make sure it isn't running when you start your server....